# How do sites like SquareSpace and Wix support multiple design templates?

Tags: web-development, architecture

How do these guys do it? I've worked on a couple multi-tenant sites and I have a hard time wrapping my head around how you would go about having each page of your site support many designs. Sure you could create a partial for each page or module for each template but that seems like a maintenance nightmare.

How would you architect a site that can support multiple design templates? I'm most familiar with Ruby on Rails but am looking for a more high level answer.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/839601)**

Comment: What do you mean by multiple design templates? Different styles? Different display on tablets/smartphones?

Comment: It almost sounds like the answer you're looking for is "because the styling is in the .css, not the .html, so you can just swap out .css files" (see http://www.csszengarden.com/ for examples). Is that at all related to what you mean by "template"?

Comment: I just used these companies as examples of ones that do something like this. I'm not asking for customer support. I'm a programmer working on a multi-tenant site and would like to support this some day. I haven't found any good resources online so I came here.

Comment: Swapping out css files would be easy enough if you're just talking about supporting multiple color themes. But I mean a totally different look and feel where content between theme 1 and 2 are completely different markup.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, the way this works is to have "components" that themselves have HTML structure, but allow their positioning within "cells" within the template. You might choose a layout that has a large cell and then three smaller cells beneath it, for example; you could then put a big image slider component in the big cell, and images with captions in the cell below. Once you have the data model, the implementation of controllers is relatively trivial.

---

Visually, the example above might look like this:

```
[       1       ]
[ 2 ] [ 3 ] [ 4 ]
```

There may be another template that is simpler, something like a blog with a sidebar:

```
[    1    ] [ 2 ]
```

There would be options for components that can be inserted into the template. You may see an image slider, for example; a blog component that pulls from a configurable back-end field; a simple photo with a caption; an ad. A rendering process might look like this:

1. Determine which site is being requested.
2. Look up the template for the site.
3. Look up the configured components for the site.
4. Do a union of all of the data requirements for the components.
5. Perform a query (or a few) for the data requirements.
6. Provide the data to the views and render them.

It is complicated in a few ways, but fundamentally it isn't very different from typical web application rendering.

Comment: Can you provide a simple example?

Comment: Sure. I'll add it to the answer.